# Adding context menu on click of tr of table(dynamic)

Tags: jquery, html, contextmenu

A table which is dynamically created , i want to add context menu on click of tr of table. code for calling the context event is working fine , but i don't know how to make context menu and its items. The code for table is:

```
function setItemForSale(itemForSale, type, xml)
{
  var itemForSaleTable = document.getElementById("custorder1");
  var itemForSaleTableHead = document.getElementById("head1");
  var itemForSaleTableBody = document.createElement("tbody");

  itemForSaleTableBody.appendChild(itemForSaleTableHead);

  $('#custorder1 tr').has('td').remove(); // Code for clearing table body

  for (var i = 0; i < itemForSale.length; i++)
  {
      var row = document.createElement("tr");

      if (row.addEventListener)
      {
          row.addEventListener('contextmenu', function (e)
          {
              $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
              zitemNo = $(this).find('td:first').text();
              z1Pkg = $(this).find('td:nth-child(8)').text();

              e.preventDefault();

          }, false);
      }
      else
      {
          row.attachEvent('oncontextmenu', function ()
          {
              alert("You've tried to open context menu");
              window.event.returnValue = false;
          });
      }

      var obj = itemForSale[i];
      var vitemno = obj["itemNo"];
      var vname = obj["name"];
      var valias = obj["alias"];
      var vbrand = obj["brand"];

      var cell = document.createElement("td");
      var cellText = document.createTextNode(vitemno);
      cell.appendChild(cellText);
      row.appendChild(cell);

      cell = document.createElement("td");
      cellText = document.createTextNode(vname);
      cell.appendChild(cellText);
      row.appendChild(cell);

      cell = document.createElement("td");
      cellText = document.createTextNode(valias);
      cell.appendChild(cellText);
      row.appendChild(cell);

      cell = document.createElement("td");
      cellText = document.createTextNode(vbrand);
      cell.appendChild(cellText);
      row.appendChild(cell);

      itemForSaleTableBody.appendChild(row);
  }
  itemForSaleTable.appendChild(itemForSaleTableBody);
  itemForSaleTable.setAttribute("border", "2");
}
```

I want to make a context menu with a label "Add" so that when add is clicked a function is called. 
Help Please.

Comment: Is the code even valid? Shows more than 5 errors for me: http://jsbin.com/mecocafivu/edit?js

Comment: What was there previously? Good. Can you make a working http://jsbin.com?

Comment: some code in if clause of eventlistener . i was trying to make menu and menu items which is not working , so i removed that

Comment: Ha ha... Whatever. If yo could make a working snippet, using http://jsbin.com, we will be able to easily assist you. Wanna go ahead?

Comment: What exactly is the question? You appear to be simply asking someone to debug your code.

Comment: @Liam i have clearly written the problem in the last line. i don't want debug, just wanna know the method of making menu and menu item. This code  doesn't have any bug but it is missing a functionality to add menu in the context EventListener block.

Comment: I don't think *"i want to make a context menu with a label "Add" so that when add is clicked a function is called"* is equal to your comment above? So it's not really clear. Anyway you've clarified somewhat. So you've attempted this change yourself? What did you get stuck on?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tutorial describing what you want to do: 
http://www.sitepoint.com/building-custom-right-click-context-menu-javascript/

To make it an actual answer, I will describe the process and maybe provide some code.

You are already adding an event to every row, great, what you need to realize is that the context menu is a regular element on the page, just like any other, you need to define it.

So here's a dummy context menu element:

```
<div id="context-menu">
</div>
```

to add elements to it, you just need to write ( or do it with javascript )

```
<div id="context-menu">
    <div id="context-menu-item-add" class="context-menu-item">
    </div>
</div>
```

now that you have the context menu element, you need to hide it in your css
and make its position absolute, so that it can be shown in any place on the page

```
#context-menu { position:absolute; display: none; }
```

now in this block of code you would do something like

```
    row.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(e) 
                    {
                                $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
                                zitemNo = $(this).find('td:first').text();
                                z1Pkg = $(this).find('td:nth-child(8)').text();

                                var contextMenu = document.getElementById("context-menu");

                                /* get actual mouse position */
                                var pageX = e.pageX;
                                var pageY = e.pageY;
                                if (pageX === undefined) 
                                {
                                    pageX = e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft + document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
                                    pageY = e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.scrollTop;
                                }

                                /* im pretty sure you need to add "px", i dont rememeber sorry */
                                contextMenu.style.display = "block";
                                contextMenu.style.top = [pageY, "px"].join("");
                                contextMenu.style.left = [pageX, "px"].join("");

                                /* i recommend returing false instead of preventing default */
                                return false;

                        }, false);
```

This code will only show the context menu at the position of click, you also need to account for edges, but I will let you figure that out yourself.

You also need to do add event listeners to every item of the context menu.

```
document.getElementById("context-menu-item-add").addEventListener("click", /* what to do on item click */)
```

The last step would be to "close" the context menu after the user has pressed on a context menu item or clicked anywhere else, so I recommend adding an event on the whole table, or event the entire document, and in every context menu listener.

EDIT:

BTW, if you're tagging it jQuery, please actually use jQuery, it does simplify the process of making a context menu, because it already has pageX and pageY built-in into its events.